# PostGIS CSV and error loading into MySQL

Tags: postgresql, mysql

I want to load spatial data into MySQL using a CSV I have generated from a PostgreSQL table and when loading it into MySQL database using phpmyadmin it complains "Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field." How best can I export PostGIS geometry into MySQL using a CSV without generating errors?

I have created a MySQL table as

```
CREATE TABLE cadastre (
  gid int(11) auto_increment NOT NULL,  
  geom MultiPolygon NOT NULL,  
  lpkey varchar(50),   
  SPATIAL INDEX(geom),   
  PRIMARY KEY (`gid`)  
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to convert your geometry to Well Known Text (WKT) in PostGIS by adding another column called WKT and fill it using

```
ST_AsText(the_geom)
```

Then on the MySQL side, convert the WKT to a geometry object using `GeomFromText`:

```
UPDATE My_Table SET the_mysql_geom = GeomFromText(wkt_from_csv, SRID)
```

[Here](http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_geomfromtext.snippet) is a good reference for the reverse of what you are looking for (though PostGIS and MySQL follow the same standard, so the syntax is the same).

Answer (score 0):

If you can access one server from the other you can use ogr2ogr to do a direct export from PostGIS / import into MySQL.

[MySQL ogr driver page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mysql.html)

[PostGIS ogr driver page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pg.html)

Answer (score 0):

ENGINE=MyISAM needs to be ENGINE=innoDB. MyISAM does not support spacial data or function calls.